# Alterar apenas as colunas editadas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo, ao tentar efetuar o update apenas nos campos que foram alterados o Entity Framework está também alterando os campos que não precisam.

Código do repositório:

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
   m_Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;            
}
```

Código do controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(BlogViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      using (var context = new UnitOfWork())
      {
         var blogDomain = Mapper.Map<BlogViewModel, Blog>(model);

         blogDomain.DateEdited = DateTime.Now;

         context.BlogRepository.Update(blogDomain);
         context.SaveChanges();

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
   }

   return View(model);
}
```

Gostaria de um auxilio para resolver esse problema.

Comment: Você pode trazer a entidade e alterar somente os campos que precisa, do jeito que você fez é alterado tudo realmente. !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível indicar para o Entity quais propriedades não terão seu estado alterado usando o `IsModified = false`, segue um exemplo:

```
public void Update(Classe minhaClasse)
{
    if (m_Context.Entry(minhaClasse).State == EntityState.Detached)
        m_Context.Set<Classe>().Attach(minhaClasse);

    m_Context.Entry(minhaClasse).State = EntityState.Modified;

    //Aqui é indicado que a propriedade nao deve ser alterada
     _context.Entry(minhaClasse).Property(p => p.DataCadastro).IsModified = false;

    m_Context.SaveChanges();   
}
```

<sub>Não sei qual arquitetura você está usando e nem seu modelo, logo pode ser ser que tenha que fazer ajustes no exemplo.</sub>